# Java make a ComboBox with entries from a text file

Tags: java

I need a drop down menu, listing all the entries from an already existing text file. I haven't really got a clue on how to do this, each entry on the text file is on a new line. This is what I have so far:

```
JComboBox cb = new JComboBox();
cb.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("names.txt"));
```

I'm receiving one warning

> References to generic type JComboBox should be parameterized

And two errors

> Items cannot be resolved or is not a field
>
> IO cannot be resolved or is not a field

Can someone point me in the right direction or give a solution? thanks very much

Comment: @Abdelhak that pretty much is all the code related to the combo box. I just have that in a class, without action listener

Comment: `I haven't really got a clue on how to do this,` - to do what? 1) read a file 2) create a combo box? Any time you have a programming problem you need to break it down into smaller steps and tell us which step you are having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

System.IO.File.ReadAllLines is a C# method, not Java.

You want to use [java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)).

[This page](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jcombobox-basic-tutorial-and-examples) shows how to use JComboBox properly with parametrization.

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't really got a clue on how to do this

To do what?

Any time you have a programming problem you need to break it down into smaller steps and tell us which step you are having problems with.

I see a couple of steps:

1. read a file - if you don't know how to read a file then you can read up on file I/O in your text book. Or you can look at the `Essential Java Classes` section from the [Java Tutotrial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) page.
2. create a combo box and load each line of data from the file into the combo box. For basics of using a combo box you can check out [How to Use a Combo Box](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

So the basic structure of you code might be something like:

```
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();

open the file

while (there are records in the file)
{
    // add the record to the combo box
}

close the file
```

I'll let you read the tutorial to fill in the blanks. I would keep the links to the tutorial handy for the basics of Java and Swing for future problems.